# Call C/C++ functions from the ExecutionEngine

Tags: llvm

I am learning llvm and wanted to do a proof of concept of an idea I have.

Basically, I want to split my compiler and my runtime. The compiler would give a .bc and the runtime would load it via ParseBitcodeFile and use the ExecutionEngine to run it. This part is working.

Now, to make system calls easily, I want to be able to implement in my runtime C/C++ functions which do all the system calls (file io, stdout printing, etc). My question is, how could I call these functions from the code from my toy compiler, which is compiled in a different step by llvm, and allow it to be used when executed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Good news: when using the JIT `ExecutionEngine`, this will *just work*. When the JIT-er finds an external symbol used by the IR which is not found in the IR itself, it looks in the JIT-ing process itself, so any symbols visible from your host program can be called.

This is explained directly in [part 4 of the LLVM tutorial](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl04.html):

> Whoa, how does the JIT know about sin and cos? The answer is
>   surprisingly simple: in this example, the JIT started execution of a
>   function and got to a function call. It realized that the function was
>   not yet JIT compiled and invoked the standard set of routines to
>   resolve the function. In this case, there is no body defined for the
>   function, so the JIT ended up calling “dlsym("sin")” on the
>   Kaleidoscope process itself. Since “sin” is defined within the JIT’s
>   address space, it simply patches up calls in the module to call the
>   libm version of sin directly.

For the gory details look at `lib/ExecutionEngine/JIT/JIT.cpp` - in particular its usage of `DynamicLibrary`.

Answer (score 13):

Eli's answer is great and you should accept it. There's another alternative, though, which is to separately compile your runtime's source files to LLVM modules (e.g. with Clang) and use `ExecutionEngine::addModule()` to add them.

It's less convenient, and it means compiling the same files twice (once for your host program, another to get `Module`s from them), but the advantage is that it enables inlining and other cross-function optimizations from your JITted code.